# Does the JAR entry point actually have to be inside the JAR?

Tags: java, maven, manifest.mf

### A bit of context

I am trying to design a minimal framework with a launcher which will be common to several projects. I am however encountering difficulties when it comes to running the JARs.

My purpose is to have a self-sufficient `java -jar` command: the MANIFEST knows the classpath and the entry point. The delicate bit is this: since I want the launcher to be common to all projects, and to be DRY-compliant, I have a specific JAR with it, which will always be on the classpath.

Now, I have trouble launching my jar:

> java -jar test.jar

should load classpath and entry point from the Manifest. It does find the Manifest, but I end up with the `Could not find or load main class`.

Launching with more explicit details *does* work:

> java -cp test.jar;lib/* org.keyboardplaying.test.TestLauncher

### My question

I did not find any specification to say whether it is possible or not, and this is not the standard case, but **can I specify in my MANIFEST.MF an entry point that will be found on classpath but is not included within my JAR?**

---

### Some more details

#### My MANIFEST.MF

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
>   Created-By: Apache Maven
>   Built-By: Chop
>   Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45
>   Main-Class: org.keyboardplaying.test.TestLauncher
>   Class-Path: lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar lib/logback-classic-1.
>    1.3.jar lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar

#### Notes for people with problems

- I previously tried `Class-Path: lib/*` which I like better, but you cannot use wild cards for classpath in Manifest<sup>1</sup>. You can still use directories, but the class loader will not examine the content of jars within this directory.

---

<sub>1. One source among others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4756762/1734119</sub>
<sub>2. Very interesting link for Class-Path entry of MANIFEST: http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.com/2011/03/jar-manifestmf-class-path-referencing.html</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the JAR entry point actually have to be inside the JAR?

No, it doesn't. It's entirely reasonable to put the launcher into a separate jar file, and so long as that's in the classpath specified by the manifest, it should be fine. Here's an example:

launch\Launchable.java:

```
package launch;

public interface Launchable {
    void launch();
}
```

launch\Launcher.java:

```
package launch;

public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("I am the launcher!");
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(args[0]);
        Launchable launchable = (Launchable) clazz.newInstance();
        launchable.launch();
    }
}
```

demo\Test.java:

```
package demo;

import launch.Launchable;

public class Test implements Launchable {
    public void launch() {
        System.out.println("I am Test, being launched");
    }
}
```

manifest.txt:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: launch.Launcher
Class-Path: launcher.jar
```

Now compile and run:

```
$ javac -d . launcher/*.java
$ javac -d . demo/*.java
$ jar cvf launcher.jar launcher
$ jar cvfm demo.jar manifest.txt demo
$ java -jar demo.jar demo.Test
I am the launcher!
I am Test, being launched
```